# Import access db in excel using a query with variables

Tags: excel, vba, query-variables

I have an issue trying to import access db through a query , but using variables
variables are macroWB and cust
macroWB refers to filepath
cust refers to selected customer name
VBA code works with fixed values
Also please advice if there are a more professional(faster) approach

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("db").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

Dim pq As Object
  For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    pq.Delete
  Next

Dim macroWB As String
macroWB = ThisWorkbook.Path
cust = Sheets("pre-filter").Range("C5").Value

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="customers Materials", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(macroWB & ""\Database2.accdb""), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""_customers Materials"" = Source{[Schema="""",Item=""customers Materials""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""_customers Materials"", each ([Cutomername] = cust))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""customers Materials"";Extended Properties=""""" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [customers Materials]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "customers_Materials"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Range("customers_Materials[[#Headers],[Cutomername]]").Select

ActiveSheet.Name = "db"
```

Comment: Is the db local(to the workbook) or on a server?  Have you tried ScreenUpdating = False? Including the where criteria in the CommandText?

Comment: hi. the issue is here source and criteria ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="customers Materials", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(macroWB & ""\Database2.accdb""), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""_customers Materials"" = Source{[Schema="""",Item=""customers Materials""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""_customers Materials"", each ([Cutomername] = cust))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""